# Compile command does not succeed with list input with Parallelization->True

Tags: parallelization, compile

J. M. suggested that I pose the following as a question, a matter arising in relation to the function `probit`:

```
SpecialFunctions`Probit; (* force autoload *)
probit = Compile[{{u, _Real}},
                 With[{d = 17/40},
                      If[Abs[u - 1/2] <= d,
                         System`StatisticalFunctionsDump`CompiledProbitCentralMinimax[u], 
                         System`StatisticalFunctionsDump`CompiledProbitAsymptotic[u]]],
                 CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True,
                                        "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
                 RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

that he gave in his answer to my question [Can I use Compile to speed up InverseCDF?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181099/can-i-use-compile-to-speed-up-inversecdf)  . In a comment, he suggested that in order to compare performance times with the code of Henrik Schumacher (also given in an earlier answer of Schumacher to the same question), one should "insert `CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True` after the `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` part" into the `probit` code, that is

```
probit = Compile[{{u, _Real}},
                 With[{d = 17/40},
                      If[Abs[u - 1/2] <= d,
                         System`StatisticalFunctionsDump`CompiledProbitCentralMinimax[u], 
                         System`StatisticalFunctionsDump`CompiledProbitAsymptotic[u]]],
                 CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True,
                                        "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
                 RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationTarget -> "C",
                 Parallelization -> True];
```

But when I use a list (as I need to)--say {1/3,1/4}--as the input to the so-augmented `probit` code I get the error message

```
CompiledFunction::pext: Instruction 12 in
CompiledFunction[{10,11.3,7900},{_Real},{{3,0,0},{3,0,5}},<<4>>,Evaluate,
LibraryFunction[/Users/Paul/Library/Mathematica/ApplicationData/CCompilerDriver/BuildFolder/
slater-71924/compiledFunction0.dylib,compiledFunction0,{{Real,0,Constant}},Real]]
calls ordinary code that can be evaluated on only one thread at a time.
```

Without `Parallelization -> True`, I don't get the error message, but the program then runs more slowly than I would hope. (I'm rather befuddled, since this specific problem did not seem to arise in some related analyses of mine yesterday.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good ol' inlining probem. Enforcing correct inlining with `With` should work. The problem was that the uninlined  `CompiledProbitCentralMinimax` and `CompiledProbitAsymptotic` enforced calls to the infamous `MainEvaluate`.

```
SpecialFunctions`Probit;
probit = With[{
    d = N[17/40],
    cf1 = System`StatisticalFunctionsDump`CompiledProbitCentralMinimax,
    cf2 = System`StatisticalFunctionsDump`CompiledProbitAsymptotic
    },
   Compile[{{u, _Real}},
    If[Abs[u - 0.5] <= d,
     cf1[u],
     cf2[u]
     ],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    Parallelization -> True,
    CompilationOptions -> {
      "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True,
      "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True
      },
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
```

Here is also `J.M.`s function `AcklamQuantile`:

```
AcklamQuantile = Block[{u}, Compile[{{u, _Real}}, #,
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True,
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ] & @@ 
    Hold[With[{a = {-39.69683028665376, 
         220.9460984245205, -275.9285104469687, 
         138.3577518672690, -30.66479806614716, 2.506628277459239}, 
       b = {-54.47609879822406, 161.5858368580409, -155.6989798598866,
          66.80131188771972, -13.28068155288572, 1}, 
       c = {-0.007784894002430293, -0.3223964580411365, \
-2.400758277161838, -2.549732539343734, 4.374664141464968, 
         2.938163982698783}, 
       d = {0.007784695709041462, 0.3224671290700398, 
         2.445134137142996, 3.754408661907416, 1.}}, 
      Which[0.02435 <= u <= 0.97575, 
       With[{v = u - 1/2}, 
         v Fold[(#1 v^2 + #2) &, 0, a]/Fold[(#1 v^2 + #2) &, 0, b]] //
         Evaluate, u > 0.97575, 
       With[{q = Sqrt[-2 Log[1 - u]]}, -Fold[(#1 q + #2) &, 0, c]/
          Fold[(#1 q + #2) &, 0, d]] // Evaluate, True, 
       With[{q = Sqrt[-2 Log[u]]}, 
         Fold[(#1 q + #2) &, 0, c]/Fold[(#1 q + #2) &, 0, d]] // 
        Evaluate]
      ]
     ]
   ];
```

Speed test against my function `cfinv` from the [linked post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181112) (running on a Haswell Quad Core):

```
T = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, {1000000}];
a = cfinv[T]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = probit[T]; // RepeatedTiming // First
c = AcklamQuantile[T]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[a - b]]
Max[Abs[a - c]]
```

> 0.0525
>
> 0.0348
>
> 0.0342
>
> 2.65592*10^-11
>
> 5.59094*10^-9

Well, J.M.'s code is indeed quite a lot faster, in particular at the tails of the distribution (where Newton's method converges slowly).

Comment: Interesting, that needs to be injected too... I guess I should edit my answer in the other question.

Comment: Misunderstanding--I (stupidly) thought the comment was of Henrik Schumacher.

Comment: Well, the "correct inlining" code above does now work on lists in my context--but it only seems to give a rather minor (1-2%) improvement over the original cfinv function of Schumacher I've been using. The AcklamQuantile function, I believe (I have to check further)  gives a more substantial improvement, but its precision is lower, so maybe I won't convert to that option either.

Comment: The AcklamQuantile function (with the CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True insertion [no "inlining" apparently needed]) gives about a 5% improvement in run time. (The improvement times I give in this comment and the previous one apply to my overall program--and not specifically to the InverseCDF-related commands. So, their improvement times for these commands themselves should be somewhat superior.)

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes sense: Now other parts of your code are becoming bottlenecks rather than the inverse CDF...

Comment: An opportunity (restart) came up, for me to continue afresh my production runs. I considered using either of J. M.'s codes instead of cfinv, but I was a little concerned by your comment in the companion posting that "The compiled method does never return Infinity or -Infinity but rather the CDF values of MachineEpsilon and 1-MachineEpsilon". Prior to using cfinv I was getting infrequent errors trying to orthogonalize matrices. I didn't know if the J. M. programs were similarly protected against such errors, since I have not been encountering them with cfinv.

Comment: @Paul, in general, compiled routines are not able to return `Infinity` results. So, if there is a possibility of hitting either $0$ or $1$ in your runs, some additional code might be necessary (e.g. returning `$MaxMachineNumber` instead).

Comment: Well, I replaced Henrik's cfinv command--that I'd been using in my production runs--with his version of the AcklamQuantile code, and lo and behold, I once again got the  "CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation" and  "Orthogonalize::mindet: Input matrix contains an indeterminate entry" error messages that cfinv  (with its MachineEpsilon commands) had "cured". I'll try the same exercise with Henrik's probit code. So, can I insert $MaxMachineNumber or MachineEpsilon into the AcklamQuantile code to avoid this--or maybe its precision is too lo?

Comment: I've now found that Henrik's probit code, as presently written, also gives me the same error messages (which to reiterate, his cfinv code does not).

Comment: Well, @Paul, then it might be better to stick with `cinv`...

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment (that is, sticking with cfinv)--while I try to further tweak my code in attempted response to the penultimate comment(s) of Martin Roberts in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231391/how-can-one-generate-an-open-ended-sequence-of-low-discrepancy-points-in-3d . That is, I'm trying to see how best to implement his quasirandom sequences (to avoid possible correlations), given that my algorithm requires generating two matrices.